# AWS EC2 PHP SDK empty BlockDeviceMappings array

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have a problem with the AWS PHP SDK. I create an instance from which I want to retrieve the VolumeId afterwards. However, the SDK returns an empty array as BlockDeviceMappings as a response.
Does anyone know what this could be?

My code:

```php
$instanceParams = [
            'ImageId' => $imageId,
            'InstanceType' => $instanceType,
            'KeyName' => $keyPair->key_pair_name,
            'MinCount' => 1,
            'MaxCount' => 1,
            'BlockDeviceMappings' => [
                [
                    'DeviceName' => '/dev/sda1',
                    'Ebs' => [
                        'DeleteOnTermination' => false,
                        'Encrypted' => false,
                        'Iops' => 3000,
                        'Throughput' => 125,
                        'VolumeSize' => $ssdCapacity,
                        'VolumeType' => 'gp3',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'SecurityGroupIds' => [$securityGroup->provider_id],
        ];

        $result = $client->runInstances($instanceParams);
        echo ($result);
```

The result:

```php
{
    "Groups": [],
    "Instances": [
        {
            ...
            "InstanceId": "i-0591f4e968ac15xxx",
            "InstanceType": "t3.micro",
           ...
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [],
            "EbsOptimized": false,
         },
   ...
    "@metadata": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "effectiveUri": "https:\/\/ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
        "headers": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "96269c92-9fe8-4606-9b7d-8cb2ec2ee233",
            "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
            "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
            "vary": "accept-encoding",
            "content-type": "text\/xml;charset=UTF-8",
            "content-length": "5731",
            "date": "Tue, 24 Oct 2023 16:45:40 GMT",
            "server": "AmazonEC2"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Thank you for your ideas :)